# Swift - AudioKit Sequencer with Oscillator (AKOscillatorBank). Frequencies wont play at higher range (MidiNote 120+)

Tags: audiokit

I'm learning how to use AudioKit. I'm trying to play around with the sequencer and an oscillator. Everything is working dandy but i noticed when i feed a higher frequency to an oscillator that is in a sequencer track, it will render the same for such frequency (MidiNote) and all that are higher. if passed the same frequency to just the oscillator you can see the variance.

my initial setup

```
let oscillator = AKOscillatorBank()
let oscillatorTrackIndex = 0
let sequencer = AKAppleSequencer()
let midi = AKMIDI()

var scale: [Int] = []
let sequenceLength = AKDuration(beats: 8.0)


func setupTracks() {
        let midiNode = AKMIDINode(node: oscillator)
        _ = sequencer.newTrack()
        sequencer.setLength(trueLength)

        AudioKit.output = midiNode
        try! AudioKit.start()

        midiNode.enableMIDI(midi.client, name: "midiNode midi in")
        sequencer.setTempo(currentTempo)
        sequencer.enableLooping()
        sequencer.play()
}
```

my method

```
func generateSequence(_ stepSize: Float = 1/4, clear: Bool = true) {
        if clear { sequencer.tracks[oscillatorTrackIndex].clear() }
        let numberOfSteps = Int(Float(sequenceLength.beats) / stepSize)

        for i in 0 ..< numberOfSteps { //4
           if i%4 == 0 {
              sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 140, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: Double(i)), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
           } else {
              sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 200, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: Double(i)), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
           }
        }
    }
```

as you can see i'm using note number **140** and **200**. when the sequencer plays these notes, they render out the same audio. if i use `.midiNoteToFrequency()` and feed these through the oscillator by itself then you can hear the difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the MIDI spec, there are only 7 bits for note number, allowing values between 0-127.  Presumably (and this might happening internally in Apple's MusicSequence, since I don't think that `AKAppleSequencer` or `AKMusicTrack` do this explicitly), values outside of this range are clamped into this range to avoid unexpected crashes.

Comment: Thanks @c_booth!! I suspected it was something along the lines i just needed a sanity check with an explanation :)